# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4', despite Mac terminal showing that bs4 has been installed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to Python and coding in general and I'm having trouble installing Beautiful Soup.

In the terminal I've run 'pip install bs4', to which it says that it has been successfully installed, however, when I run 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, in a JupyterNotebook in VSCode I'm given the error message quoted in the title. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Vscode may use its own Python installation or virtual environment.